# Blending mode in SVG

Tags: svg, vector-graphics, svg-filters

I am stuck with a problem in SVG blending mode. I have four paths in SVG and I want to composite them with formula: (1*2) + (3*4), i.e. Path 1 and Path 2 should be blended using multiply mode, similarly path 3 and path 4 should be blended using multiply and then they should be combined together using screen blending mode to produce the final image. Any help/reference will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this right now is by using [SVG filters](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/filters.html). There are the `feBlend` and `feComposite` filter primitives that let you do this.

There's a specification for [SVG Compositing](http://dev.w3.org/SVG/modules/compositing/publish/), but that's in its early stages, and not yet implemented.

Comment: I know feBlend can work on background image. But in my case, I want to use feBlend on paths 3 and 4, independent of the background. How is this possible?